# JQuery .selectedIndex = 0; not working on all selected field

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select name="wpcf-others" id="abc" class="myzebra-control myzebra-select">
<option value="wpcf-field123">General Work Jobs</option>
<option value="wpcf-fields--1">Journalist/Editors Jobs</option>
<option value="wpcf-4868b877-1">Publishing Jobs</option>
<option value="wpcf-fields-2fb08-1">Others Jobs</option>
</select>
<select name="wpcf-otsdrs" id="abc" class="myzebra-control myzebra-select">
<option value="wpcf-field123">General Work Jobs</option>
<option value="wpcf-fields--1">Journalist/Editors Jobs</option>
<option value="wpcf-4868b877-1">Publishing Jobs</option>
<option value="wpcf-fields-2fb08-1">Others Jobs</option>
</select>
```

Js code

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$("select").prepend('<option value="">- select -</option>');
$("select")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

The Jscode above prepend the value to - select - successfully, but only make the first dropdown selection to "- select -"

http://jsfiddle.net/J7PhF/7/

What should i do to make all select field to select "- select -" ?

Comment: Why don't you simply add the selected attribute to the option? See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7PhF/8/)

Comment: `$("select").val('');`

Comment: @skube why dont you post it as answer, i will vote up for u, works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Please make use of `.val()` method to achieve your need. Since you are having the value of default option as `""`, I would suggest you to use this  `$("select").val("");`

Try this,

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("select").prepend('<option value="0">- select -</option>');
    $("select").val("");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/J7PhF/9/)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, I'm posting as an answer...

Why don't you simply add the selected attribute to the option?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("select").prepend('<option value="" selected>- select -</option>');
    $("select")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7PhF/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the selectedIndex property on all the selects. So instead of

```
$("select")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

You want to do:

```
$("select").prop('selectedIndex', 0)
```

And it should work as you expect.